# outlook macro change item.to recipient address to another while sending a message

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I want to change recipient's email address when sending a message. I don't know if I should work with item.to or rec.addressentry or myrecipient.

I want it to work like when you enter example@mail.com then it will send it to example2@mail.com, it can rewrite while pressing send button or just send to the example2.

I want to to start the macro at the startup so it should be after startup event and I guess it should be itemsend event.

I tried these:
not working

```
'Item = MailItem
     If Item.To = "example@mail.com" Then
         Item.To = "example2@mail.com"
```

does not close the message window

```
If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
   Dim newEm As String

   Dim Rec As Recipient
        Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
        Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        myItem.Body = Item.Body
        myItem.HTMLBody = Item.HTMLBody
        myItem.Subject = Item.Subject
        Cancel = True


    If InStr(1, Rec.AddressEntry, "example@mail.com", vbTextCompare) Then
        newEm = "example2@mail.com"

   End If

    Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add(newEm)
    myRecipient.Type = Rec.Type
  Next

   myItem.Send

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Item.To = ChangeSMTPRecipient(Item, "example@mail.com", "example2@mail.com")

End Sub
```

```
Function ChangeSMTPRecipient(mail As Outlook.MailItem, FromSMTP, ToSMTP) As String
On Error Resume Next
    Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
    Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim pa As Outlook.propertyAccessor
    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

    ChangeSMTPRecipient = ""

    Set recips = mail.Recipients
    For Each recip In recips
        Set pa = recip.propertyAccessor
        RecipNew = pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
        If RecipNew = FromSMTP Then RecipNew = ToSMTP
        ChangeSMTPRecipient = ChangeSMTPRecipient & IIf(ChangeSMTPRecipient = "", "", "; ") &     RecipNew
    Next
On Error GoTo 0
    End Function
```

Comment: if I have put as example my main email as test then it rewrote it to example 2 but didn't send any email, if i have used example3 and example2 then again no message. Isn't there some easier way it does not have to be that "cloaked", it will just as soon as you hit send button direct to example2 (example1 will not see the message)

Comment: I have added something that will try to send the email 
Set myItem = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
myItem.To = ChangeSMTPRecipient(Item, "example@gmail.com", "example2@gmail.com")
myItem.Send

but now it sends it to the example and empty mail in example2